Does saying "Yes" on spam calls actually lead to this "Yes" being used elsewhere?
There's lots of reports like Don't say yes when caller asks 'Can you hear me now?', but even this article says:

"...that 'Yes' answer you gave could later be edited to make it sound like you authorized a major purchase," the BBB said in its alert.

Do any financial institutions have such easily-fooled systems with voice recognition but no other second factor? And how would that work anyway? From the same article:

no reports in the Scam Tracker mention monetary loss

That's reassuring. And also from the same article:

That yes could also confirm the scammer got a real working number

That's really the only thing I can see being the objective, and these articles are just for general raising awareness of phone spam.
So, my scepticism is around the assumption that there are financial institutions that will use your recorded "Yes" to authorise transactions, or that there has been cases where a recorded "Yes" has been found to be legally binding.
(Or is this better on Money.se?)

What articles are you referring to? If you're referring to the ones in the linked question, can you link to them here as well?

@F1Krazy All the quotes are from the same article; I've added text to make it clearer, I hope.
